# Using JQuery to scroll an iframe from the parent

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent, scrolltop

I'm trying to scroll an iframe from the parent window using JQuery. In other words, set up scroll buttons on the parent page that scroll the child iframe. It works fine with JavaScript, using:

```
function scroller(howMuch) 
{
        var myIframe = document.getElementById('iframeid');

        myIframe.contentWindow.scrollBy(0,howMuch);
}
```

then calling the function from:

```
<a href="javascript:scroller(-50)">Scroll Up 50 px</a>
```

But trying to use JQuery to use animate() instead of the clunky scrollBy() hasn't been easy. I've tried

```
$('#iframeid').contentWindow.animate({scrollTop : 50});
```

for example. I'm fairly certain this is how to access the iframe's contentWindow from JQuery- can't find much on the subject. One problem could be that the parent page is set to scroll: none (the iframe is set to default). Could this be the dealbreaker or am I missing something else? I realize I can code a delay loop in JavaScript but this has piqued my curiosity.

Comment: Try giving the parent scroll:auto as well, then you can at least rule that out.

Comment: Also, you have not described how this code fails, are you getting any JS errors, which? I'm guessing `$('#iframeid').contentWindow` is invalid since $() returns a jquery object. `$('#iframeid')[0].contentWindow` might do the trick.

Comment: is the iframe page on the same domain as the parent?

Comment: Same domains, yes. The code gives no errors, and I've tried giving everyone scroll:auto.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues here, definitely one.

jQuery doesn't understand `contentWindow()` in this string, for this you'll need to use  `contents()`.

If you're able to manipulate the contents of the iframe (same-domain), then you can use

```
$('element').on('mousedown', function(){
  $('iframe').contents().animate({ scrollTop : 50 });
});
```

And holding that down will scroll the contents. Try it out.

Comment: Interesting... Still not working. It returns no error and the script runs all the way through.
It's running fine and even runs through your line of script but no scrolling happens. The iframe is on the same domain, yes. 
I can't find much documentation on iframes in jQuery besides calling the pages inside. And scrolling the parent from the child. hmm.

Comment: @user1527688 for your code, you should probably use `$('element').on('mousedown', function(){
  $('body').find('iframe').contents().find('body').animate({ scrollTop : 50 });
});` ...do you get a `Error: Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'`?

Comment: No access errors- the child page is in the same directory as the parent. I'll try using find('body') - that might be the problem.

Comment: Hmm. This still didn't work. This should be called with $(document).ready, correct? 'element' is the id of a button or link, and find(iframe) finds all iframes on the page?